# Use common JSP with a custom Servlet and Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

(Oups.. Sorry for my english :) )

In my web application, Struts2 is used as the main Servlet dispatcher and filter. But For some reasons, i have a custom filter and a custom servlet used for a specific url "**/book**".

But I have some commons jsp... i had some issues when the custom Servlet should display my request attributes in the JSP because of the struts tags (implemented before). So i changed these tag by the jstl taglibs and it works now.

But... In one JSP, the main (lol)... I have a search form.. **This JSP is included in several JSPs and could be called by Struts and the custom Servlet.**.

With only Struts the tag was "*< s:form>*.." and when the form was submitted, all sended values was kept in the input... But now, because of the custom Servlet i use a simple html form which is calling the struts action "*search.do*".

**As source code is below:**

```
<form method="post" action="<c:out value="${contextPath}"/>/search.do" name="search" id="search">
<input type="text" id="search_searchWord" value="" maxlength="200" size="100" name="searchWord">

<div align="right">
<input type="submit" value="Ok" name="searchButton" id="search">
</div>

<select id="search_searchCrit" name="searchCrit">
<option value="0">Crit1</option>
<option value="1">Crit2</option>
<option value="2">Crit3</option>
</select>

</form>
```

**My problem is the search word and the selected option are refreshed after the submit. I need to keep them !**

Is there a way to use the struts taglibs with a Standard Servlet ?

Or Do you have another solution to keep the submitted information ?

Thanks all !

Comment: Can't you simply use two different "common" JSP, one for the Actions, the other for the servlet ?

Comment: Hi, No because this JSP could be updated with other functionnalities. Thanks but i found a solution.

Comment: Consider sharing it by answering your own question to help future visitors with the same problem

Comment: i was writing it when you have added this comment :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of @java_seeker.

In my Struts action, i got the request through this way :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
request.setAttribute("searchWord", this.getSearchWord());
```

There is two different way to do this, see: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-get-the-httpservletrequest-in-struts-2/

The attribute is setted in each method (in the action) that could refresh the page.

Then, i just recovered and set the attribute from the request as a variable with a jstl tag and display it as the value of my html input:

```
    <c:set var="searchWord" value='<%=request.getAttribute("searchWord") %>' />
    <input type="text" id="search_searchWor" value='<c:out value="${searchWord}" />' name="searchWord">
```

For the  , i just used an `<c:choose><c:when test=""></c:when><c:otherwise><c:otherwise></c:choose>` to set the selected choice.

Now all value are always displayed. Maybe it's not the very good way to display share the same JSP between a standard servlet and a Struts action, but it works. I'm open to try a better solution if you have one! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

> take each field value from the input field and write js function to fill each field in jsp source code of your page.

```
function selectedValue(){  
    var value =<%=request.getParameter("searchCrit")%>;  
    if(value !=null)  
        {
          document.getElementById('search_searchCrit').innerHTML=value;          

        }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me, i didn't use this solution because javascript is not necessarily required. I just take the `<%=request.getAttribute("searchCrit")%>`, define a jstl variable and display it as the value in the html input.